# Adding buttons like the picture

Tags: button

I am trying to create buttons like the picture below, what controls should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://design.google.com/icons/ ora if you are building an hybrid app with ionic you can use its library of icon http://ionicons.com/

Comment: I mean which controls should I use, ImageButton ?

Comment: By control you maan an HTML tag?